# Regex to match multiple string conditions

Tags: regex, substring

I have a need to capture two different string types returned by a query.  The first string has data that needs to be trimmed off while the second string is just text.

```
Review / Sign Changes  (Doe,John Howard - 555-00-5555)
City & State for Current Visit
```

I tried

```
(?\<Group1\>(?:(.)  ())|.\*
(?\<Group1\>\*.\[a-zA-Z\] )|(.\*)
```

I expected:

```
Review / Sign Changes
City & State for Current Visit
```

I'm not strong in Regex but I try :)  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex:

```
^[^(]+
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/XoF6ss/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `[^(]+` | any character except: `(` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Thank you so much.  There are two white spaces in front of the "(".  I was trying to input \s{2} in the solution to remove those but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

If the formatting of the first string is consistent, you can skip regex and just split the string by two spaces and take the first part. For the second string, I see no changes at all so you shouldn't need a regex there.